# Simple C# WinForm app shows to have 3 threads in visual studio. Task Manger show 14-16 threads. Why?

Tags: c#, multithreading, taskmanager

I'm creating a very simple WinForm app in C#. With nothing but the form. No other code. When I hit pause and look at the threads window in Visual Studio, i see 3 threads. 1 main thread and 2 worker threads (used for may be GC or JIT)

When I open Task Manager when application is running then I see 14-16 threads for the application. I don't understand what is creating these other threads. Can anyone help?[image]

Comment: A form so it doesn't exit has a block.   The main is in Program.cs which call the main form constructor.  The main form inherits Form which contains the block.  It also starts a background process that manages the event like the click events.  So you have 1) The main class 2) The form class 3) The event handler.

Comment: Could you please take a screen shot your Task Manager and attach to here? I checked on my side, and it is only 1 thread.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why do you care? What is your underlying problem?

Comment: There is no one-to-one mapping between a managed thread and an OS thread, and task manager is not an ideal tool for developers who need to profile an app. I choose to believe Visual Studio.

Comment: Added screenshot. I like @lesscode answer and I will investigate that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional worker threads could be there for any number of reasons in a WinForms app, including:

- Thread pool threads that were used briefly and are waiting for additional work (the thread pool will kill them eventually if nothing is going on)
- GDI+/DDE will usually create a background thread
- CLR Finalizer thread

It's likely that most of the threads you're seeing are the first kind.

**Tip**: If you want to see these threads in the Visual Studio debugger's Threads panel, make sure your project is configured to "Enable native code debugging" (under the Debug tab in Project Settings).